# Ternary operator in LINQ queries used for handle nullable DateTime throws the exception

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate

I have some filter class. This class has nullable date field.

```
public class Filter
{
   DateTime? date;
}
```

Then I have some LINQ query, which uses IQueryable object of nHibernate. In one of the conditions I have:

```
Where(x=>...
some expression
&& !Model.date.HasValue ? true : (x.fooDate.Date == Model.date.Value.Date)
&& some expresion
```

Unfortunately it throws the exception (namely PartialEvaluationExceptionExpression). Probably it tries to evaluate the false path of the expression while Model.date.Value does not exist.

How can I handle this? I know I can do something like that:

```
if(!Model.Date.HasValue)
{
    Where(x=>...
    some expression
    //Mentioned condition is omitted
    && some expression
}
else
{
    Where(x=>...
    some expression
    && (x.fooDate.Date == Model.date.Value.Date)
    && some expresion 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've decided to omit the problem by dividing the query as follows:

```
query = Where(x=>...
some expression
&& some expresion
&& some expresion
&& some expresion);

if(Model.date.HasValue)
{
    query = query.Where(x=>...
        x.fooDate.Date == Model.date.Value.Date);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, why don't just write it as:

```
Where(x=>...
    !Model.date.HasValue ? 
       true : 
       (Model.date.Value != null 
         && x.fooDate.Date == Model.date.Value.Date)
```

**Update**

Looking to this expression more precisely - I don't think `Model.date.Value` can be null in second branch of expression. More likely it's `x.fooDate`, so second branch should look like:

```
(x.fooDate != null && x.fooDate.Date == Model.date.Value.Date)
```

Comment: @Landeeyo well, you haven't specified initially that it is `PartialEvaluationExceptionExpression` thrown, so I've supposed it was `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: @AndyKorneyev I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I'd separate it out in to an or:

```
Where(x=>...
    (Model.date == null || x.fooDate.Date == Model.date.Value.Date)
```

I'm not sure HasValue will work, and I don't have an easy way of testing from here, so I've changed it to a null check.

Comment: This code also throws the PartialEvaluationExceptionExpression.